# Quest system best design

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, oop, database-design

I want to be able to create quests for users on a RPG website.

My problem is I want to have many types of quests such as killing a certain number of monsters or doing  a certain number of homeworks. Of course I could create a class for each type of quest but there are unique quests that are unlike any other.

I'd like to be able to show a special output for each type of quest of course.

The real problem is that I have to store them in the db and that doesn't make sense to create a hundred tables...

Have you got any idea of a good design for this kind of thing?

Comment: Without the details of all the sorts of quests, and what you want to do with each quest it's difficult to answer this.

Comment: In fact, I think I won't give the details because there are really many types and my question is about the way to manage them whatever their type.

Comment: You can have one table for each main type, and handle the unique quest separately. Also, not all quest info has to be stored in the db.

Comment: That's right but where can I store it if not in the db ? (and the progess of the users too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you are asking for  [STI](http://rails-bestpractices.com/posts/45-use-sti-and-polymorphic-model-for-multiple-uploads)